# Docker compose create kafka topics

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

**Problem**: Cannot create topics from docker-compose. I need to create kafka topics before I run a system under test. Planning to use it as a part of the pipeline, hence using UI is not an option.

Note: it takes ~15 seconds for kafka to be ready so I would need to put a sleep for 15 seconds prior to adding the topics.

**Possible solution**:

1. create a shell.sh file with commands to wait for 15 sec then add a bunch of topics
2. create a dockerfile for it
3. include that docker image in the docker-compose.yml just before starting the system under test

**Current flow**:

1. create zookeeper - OK
2. create kafka1 - OK
3. rest-proxy - OK
4. create topics **<- PROBLEM**
5. create SUT - OK

**Current docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '2'
services:
zookeeper:
image: docker.io/confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.4.1
hostname: zookeeper
container_name: zookeeper
ports:
- "2181:2181"
environment:
ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

Kafka1:
image: docker.io/confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.4.1
hostname: Kafka1
container_name: Kafka1
depends_on:
- zookeeper
ports:
- "9092:9092"
- "9101:9101"
environment:
KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: Kafka1
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://Kafka1:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: Kafka1:29092
CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'

rest-proxy:
image: docker.io/confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:5.4.1
depends_on:
- zookeeper
- Kafka1
ports:
- 8082:8082
hostname: rest-proxy
container_name: rest-proxy
environment:
KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: rest-proxy
KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'Kafka1:29092'
KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8082"
KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'


topics:
image: topics:latest
hostname: topics
container_name: topics
depends_on:
- zookeeper
- Kafka1
- rest-proxy


sut:
image: sut:latest
hostname: sut
container_name: sut
depends_on:
- zookeeper
- Kafka1
- rest-proxy
ports:
- 5000:80
```

**Current Dockerfile for topics container**:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

ADD topics.sh /usr/local/bin/topics.sh

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/topics.sh

CMD /usr/local/bin/topics.sh
```

**Current topics.sh file**:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Start: Sleep 15 seconds"
sleep 30;
wait;
echo "Begin creating topics"
docker exec Kafka1 kafka-topics --create --if-not-exists --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1 --topic MY_AWESOME_TOPIC_ONE
docker exec Kafka1 kafka-topics --create --if-not-exists --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1 --topic MY_AWESOME_TOPIC_TWO
echo "Done creating topics"
```

**Current output**:

```
/usr/local/bin/topics.sh: 1: /usr/local/bin/topics.sh: ï»¿#!/bin/sh: not found
Start: Sleep 15 seconds
Begin creating topics
/usr/local/bin/topics.sh: 8: /usr/local/bin/topics.sh: docker: not found
/usr/local/bin/topics.sh: 9: /usr/local/bin/topics.sh: docker: not found
/usr/local/bin/topics.sh: 10: /usr/local/bin/topics.sh: docker: not found
/usr/local/bin/topics.sh: 11: /usr/local/bin/topics.sh: docker: not found
/usr/local/bin/topics.sh: 12: /usr/local/bin/topics.sh: docker: not found
/usr/local/bin/topics.sh: 13: /usr/local/bin/topics.sh: docker: not found
/usr/local/bin/topics.sh: 14: /usr/local/bin/topics.sh: docker: not found
/usr/local/bin/topics.sh: 15: /usr/local/bin/topics.sh: docker: not found
Done creating topics
```

Topics are not created. I'm stuck. Please help.

Comment: As a general rule, programs in containers can't run `docker` commands without being given unrestricted root-level access over the whole host.  Directly using Kafka's admin API or invoking the Kafka CLI tools would be a better choice.  You also can't use software you haven't installed in the image: your Dockerfile doesn't install the `docker` CLI tool, which produces the `docker: not found` error you see.

Comment: Here is another example [create a topic when start docker compose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76281698/12727918)

Answer (score 102):

The simplest way is to start a separate container inside the docker-compose file (called `init-kafka` in the example below) to launch the various `kafka-topics --create ...` commands, while first making it wait for Kafka to be reachble by simply running `kafka-topics --list ...`.

Like this:

```
version: '2.1'
services:

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.1.1
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181

  # reachable on 9092 from the host and on 29092 from inside docker compose
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.1.1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
    expose:
      - '29092'
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: '1'
      KAFKA_MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS: '1'

  init-kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.1.1
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    entrypoint: [ '/bin/sh', '-c' ]
    command: |
      "
      # blocks until kafka is reachable
      kafka-topics --bootstrap-server kafka:29092 --list

      echo -e 'Creating kafka topics'
      kafka-topics --bootstrap-server kafka:29092 --create --if-not-exists --topic my-topic-1 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1
      kafka-topics --bootstrap-server kafka:29092 --create --if-not-exists --topic my-topic-2 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1

      echo -e 'Successfully created the following topics:'
      kafka-topics --bootstrap-server kafka:29092 --list
      "
```

When running it, the `init-kafka` container should log something like:

```
docker logs docker_init-kafka_1


[2021-10-12 02:00:28,728] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (kafka/172.24.0.3:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2021-10-12 02:00:28,832] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (kafka/172.24.0.3:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2021-10-12 02:00:29,033] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (kafka/172.24.0.3:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2021-10-12 02:00:29,335] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (kafka/172.24.0.3:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)


Creating kafka topics
Created topic my-topic-1.
Created topic my-topic-2.
Successfully created the following topics:
my-topic-1
my-topic-2
```

Comment: This should be the right answer to solve the problem. Thanks for share it.

Comment: Such a great solution. With the default configuration that was used for mine, I had to switch it out to be kafka:9092, but once I figured that out, it worked like a charm. This should definitely be the accepted answer.

Comment: as @adprocas mentioned, bootstrap-server should be kafka:9092 according to the configuration

Answer (score 6):

This solution allows one to create a topic from the docker-compse.yml

- Refer to the DockerFile of your respective kafka image service
- Take note of the last command in respective dockerFile image (DockerHub repo of image/Image Layers)
- In my case for image **blockconfluentinc/cp-kafka:latest**, the last command which starts the kafka service is "/etc/confluent/docker/run"
- Hence in your docker-compose.yml include the below command

  `command: sh -c "((sleep 15 && kafka-topics --create --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 3 --topic topicName)&) && /etc/confluent/docker/run "`

This will start the kafka service, delay for 15 seconds then create a topic.

Please note that we are assuming it takes 15 seconds for the kafka service to be fully operational

```
    kafka:
        image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
        depends_on:
            - zookeeper
        ports:
            - "29092:29092"
        environment:
            KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
            KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
            KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
            KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
            KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
            KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
        command: sh -c "((sleep 15 && kafka-topics --create --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 3 --topic quick-starter)&) && /etc/confluent/docker/run ">
```

Answer (score 3):

I expanded on @Svend's answer that I think worth sharing.

In this version, you simply make a `seeds` directory next to your `docker-compose.yml` and `touch topic` files in there. Every file in there represents
a single topic to be created automatically. Moreover, you can add "seed/default messages" for each topic. To add seed messages to a topic simply
add each one as a newline in the topic you desire.

Seed files are inspired by this, however this implementation is not as extensive: https://github.com/provectus/kafka-ui/blob/master/documentation/compose/kafka-ui.yaml

```yaml
  init-kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.3
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    volumes:
      # create empty files in the directory to make topics and filled files as
      # seeds where each line is a message.
      - ./seeds/:/data/
    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
    command: |
      "
      # blocks until kafka is reachable
      kafka-topics --bootstrap-server kafka:29092 --list
      # alternatively with cp: cub kafka-ready -b kafka:29092 1 30 &&

      # just to make sure everything else like UI and microservices are done
      sleep 5

      echo 'Creating kafka topics'
      # For file in seeds directory create channels and feed the data.
      for file in /data/*; do
          seed=\"$$(basename \"$$file\")\"
          # TODO add SEED,X,Y variable support
          kafka-topics --bootstrap-server kafka:29092 \\
              --create --if-not-exists --topic $$seed \\
              --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1

          # If seeds are just touched files, just create the topic and do not
          # feed it the seed.
          [ \"$$(du "$$file" | grep -o \"[0-9]*\")\" = \"0\" ] ||
              kafka-console-producer --bootstrap-server kafka:29092 \\
                  --topic $$seed < $$file
      done

      echo 'Successfully created the following topics:'
      kafka-topics --bootstrap-server kafka:29092 --list
      "
```

Answer (score 2):

### Variant 1: Run topic.sh (just the kafka-topics --create in another docker container)

Sorry for providing no full example but let me share the idea:

1. Create a separate docker container 'kafka-setup' which is just required to get the kafka command-line tools. In that replace the startup command to execute some (good enough) wait operations and runs the `/kafka/topic_creator.sh` (with host:port-parameter of zookeeper and kafka) which is injected via volume. After that script is executed a file `K_OUTPUT_FILE` is created and exposed also via volume (prerequisite before calling docker-compose up, the file needs to be deleted).

Snippet from docker-compose.yml (./kafka folder contains the topic creator script, ./output gets the topics created file 'kafka-done.txt'):

```
  # This "container" is a helper to pre-create topics
  kafka-setup:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.4.3
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    volumes:
      - ./kafka:/kafka
      - ./output:/output
    command: "bash -c 'chmod +x /kafka/topic_creator.sh && \
                       /kafka/topic_creator.sh /kafka/topics.txt $$K_ZK $$K_KAFKA && \
                       touch \"$${K_OUTPUT_FILE}\" && chmod a+rw  \"$${K_OUTPUT_FILE}\"'"
    environment:
      K_ZK: localhost:22181
      K_KAFKA: localhost:19092
      K_OUTPUT_FILE: "/output/kafka-done.txt"

      # dummy values
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: ignored
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: ignored
    network_mode: host
```

2. To run everything in the right order

bash script snippet:

```
K_SETUP_OUTPUT="./output"
mkdir -p "$K_SETUP_OUTPUT"
rm -f "$K_SETUP_OUTPUT/kafka-done.txt"

# Start stuff
docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --build --remove-orphans

wait_for_file "$K_SETUP_OUTPUT/kafka-done.txt"
sleep 5
# do your stuff here (e.g.  read -r -p "Press any key to continue..." key )
do_something
```

with wait_for_file function

```
function wait_for_file {
    local name=$1
    echo "File waiting ${name}."
    seconds=0
    while [[ "$seconds" -lt "$timeout"  && ! -f "$name" ]];
    do
      echo -n .
      seconds=$((seconds+1))
      sleep 1
    done

    if [ "$seconds" -lt "$timeout" ]; then
      echo "${name} created (${seconds}s)!"
    else
      echo "  ERROR: not found ${name}" >&2
      exit 1
    fi
}
```

How it works in sequence:

1. run the test script
2. create folders and delete ./output/kafka-done.txt
3. execute docker-compose up
4. in kafka-setup first wait for availability of zookeeper and kafka ports
5. run ./kafka/topic_creator.sh with parameters for zookeeper and kafka ports
6. create ./output/kafka-done.txt
7. wait_for_file ./output/kafka-done.txt succeeds
8. do_something .. that's your tests or whatever

### Variant 2: Just allow docker to run without root

See [Manage Docker as a non-root user](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/)

Answer (score 2):

I needed to solve the topic creation myself and as I had the liberty of choosing kafka image of my preference I chose [wurstmeister kafka docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/wurstmeister/kafka) which allows for topic specification using env variable `KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS` like so:

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 192.168.99.100
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "test:1:1"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Here is a link to [docker-compose example](https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker/blob/master/docker-compose-single-broker.yml).

Another advantage for me was ARM64 version being available, just had to switch the zookeeper to [official one](https://hub.docker.com/_/zookeeper).

Comment: It does not work!

Comment: modify the KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME in docker-compose.yml to match your docker host IP (Note: Do not use localhost or 127.0.0.1 as the host ip if you want to run multiple brokers.)

Answer (score 1):

If to use the most popular Kafka docker image right now (beginning of 2024), **bitnami/kafka**, then it supports running of custom init scripts from **/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*** which is basically what we need.

First create two scripts with following content:

**init-kafka-topics.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh

KT="/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh"

echo "Waiting for kafka..."
"$KT" --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list

echo "Creating kafka topics"
"$KT" --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --create --if-not-exists --topic yourTopicGoesHere --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1

echo "Successfully created the following topics:"
"$KT" --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list
```

**run-init-kafka-topics.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh

/init-kafka-topics.sh &

exit 0
```

Then copy or mount them into bitnami/kafka container:

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: "3"

services:
  kafka:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    volumes:
      - "./kafka/run-init-kafka-topics.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/run-init-kafka-topics.sh:ro"
      - "./kafka/init-kafka-topics.sh:/init-kafka-topics.sh:ro"
    environment:
      # KRaft settings
      - KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID=0
      - KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES=controller,broker
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=0@kafka:9093
      # Listeners
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES=CONTROLLER
      - KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=PLAINTEXT
      # Misc
      - KAFKA_CFG_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE=true
```

This way, when kafka container starts, it calls **entrypoint.sh** which calls **/opt/bitnami/scripts/kafka/setup.sh** which then calls **kafka_custom_init_scripts** function from */opt/bitnami/scripts/libkafka.sh* which then looks for and executes scripts from *$KAFKA_INITSCRIPTS_DIR*.

*$KAFKA_INITSCRIPTS_DIR* is set to /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d by default.

**init-kafka-topics.sh** will run in a background and wait for Kafka to be up, then will create the topics you need.

Answer (score -1):

`ubuntu` container doesn't have docker installed.

It also doesn't have the `kafka-topics` command, so instead you should re-use the `cp-enterprise-kafka` image that you've already pulled and change the ENTRYPOINT or CMD to be your script but running the kafka-topics command directly

Or replace your Kafka container with wurstmeister/kafka and add an environment variable for creating the topics

Answer (score -2):

please include docker path in volume of kafka container in compose file of kafka service add `-v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker`