# Confluent go client - How to create a topic on a cluster?

Tags: docker, go, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

We are writing integration test cases, to produce messages using [confluent kafka producer api](https://docs.confluent.io/clients-confluent-kafka-go/current/overview.html#initialization) and then consume using [consumer api](https://docs.confluent.io/clients-confluent-kafka-go/current/overview.html#id1), with local kafka docker container setup(from a docker image `confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.0`).

Before producing the message, we need to create a topic on a cluster in kafka container.

---

As per the confluent [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka-rest/api.html#post--clusters-cluster_id-topics):

`POST /clusters/{cluster_id}/topics` creates a new topic.

What should be the value of cluster id? Is there a different api to create cluster id?

If there is no api, can we create kafka topic using another docker container?

Comment: @DavidMaze Is this query related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64865361/docker-compose-create-kafka-topics

Comment: curl --silent -X GET localhost:8090/kafka/v3/clusters | jq for your question on how to get cluster id

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you're looking at the REST Proxy documentation for the Go client. You can do this all in the Go code without another container

What you need is an AdminClient, which takes the bootstrap-servers like a producer/consumer would

```
a, err := kafka.NewAdminClient(&kafka.ConfigMap{"bootstrap.servers": broker})
...
results, err := a.CreateTopics( ... )
```

e.x. https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/blob/master/examples/admin_create_topic/admin_create_topic.go

Comment: So, just a kafka container from image `confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.0` would suffice?

Comment: You can use any Kafka container. Not sure how that is relevant to your question of needing to write test code in Go.

Comment: Goal is to write test code that creates a new topic, produce messages into that topic & consume messages from that topic. So, I need a local kafka container for doing this.

Comment: Sure, and you can use any Kafka container. If it is specifically for testing, you might want to checkout [`testcontainers-go`](https://golang.testcontainers.org/quickstart/gotest/)

Comment: So, `testcontainers-go` does not require writing a docker-compose file to stand up the containers?

Comment: You can optionally use a compose file, as listed in the sidebar there in the docs under features