# How do I create a Kafka topic using a docker-compose file?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I'm new to Kafka and I am trying to create a demo Kafka server and work with it.

I have already created Zookeeper and Kafka containers using a docker-compose file and they are started and running fine.

If I `docker exec` into the Kafka container and run:

`kafka-topics --create --zookeeper zookeeper-1 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic demo-topic`

the topic is created successfully... But I would like to spin up the Kafka broker and then programmatically create the topics without user interaction (Will ultimately be for a pipeline)

I've tried two different Kafka images (other was confluentinc/cp-kafka)... I have also tried changing **bash** to **sh** under *kafka-1.command*

Could really do with some help here. Below is my docker-compose file and the error response I'm getting in my terminal for bitnami image & for confluent image.

**ERROR (BITNAMI)**
`/opt/bitnami/scripts/kafka/entrypoint.sh: line 27: exec: bash -c "kafka-topics --create --zookeeper zookeeper-1 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic demo-topic": not found`

**ERROR (CONFLUENT)**
`Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "bash -c \"kafka-topics --create --zookeeper zookeeper-1 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic demo-topic\"": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown`

**DOCKER-COMPOSE.YAML**

```
services:
  zookeeper-1:
    container_name: zookeeper-1
    image: zookeeper
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      - ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181
    volumes: 
    - ./config/zookeeper-1/zookeeper.properties:/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties
  kafka-1:
    container_name: kafka-1 
    image: bitnami/kafka
    depends_on: 
      - zookeeper-1
    ports: 
      - 29092:29092
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper-1:2181
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:29092
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
    command:
      - bash -c "kafka-topics --create --zookeeper zookeeper-1 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic demo-topic"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For both errors, the command you are providing is being appended to the container's entrypoints, which do not accept bash commands... You would need to override both the entrypoint and the command, as well as give the full path to the `kafka-topics` script since it is not on the `$PATH`.

However, you cannot do this with the `command` on the same container as the broker because that overrides the command that actually starts the server.

You will need a secondary "init container" like below that creates the topics , but it would be easier for you to write this topic creation logic into your own producer/consumer applications with an `AdminClient.createTopics` call (assuming Java).

The `wurstmeister/kafka` Docker image has an environment variable `KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS` for this purpose, or just use `docker-compose exec kafka-1 "..."` after the containers are up

---

init container example

```yaml
services:
  kafka:
    image: &kafka-image bitnami/kafka:3.6
    ...
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "kafka-topics.sh", "--bootstrap-server=localhost:9092", "--list"]
      start_period: 15s
      interval: 10s

  init-kafka:
    image: *kafka-image
    working_dir: /opt/bitnami/kafka/bin
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    depends_on:
      kafka:
        condition: service_healthy
    command: |
      kafka-topics.sh --create --if-not-exists --topic foo --replication-factor=1 --partitions=3 --bootstrap-server kafka:9092
```

Comment: Sadly, `wurstmeister/kafka` is not available as of 2023-11-19 anymore.

Comment: IMO, good. The repo hasn't had any commits since 2022

Answer (score 2):

you can change your DOCKER-COMPOSE.YAML like this

```
  zookeeper-1:
    container_name: zookeeper-1
    image: zookeeper
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      - ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181
    volumes: 
    - ./config/zookeeper-1/zookeeper.properties:/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties
  kafka-1:
    container_name: kafka-1 
    image: bitnami/kafka
    depends_on: 
      - zookeeper-1
    ports: 
      - 29092:29092
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper-1:2181
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:29092
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --list" ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

  init-kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.1.1
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    entrypoint: [ '/bin/sh', '-c' ]
    command: |
      "
      # blocks until kafka is reachable
      kafka-topics --bootstrap-server kafka:29092 --list
      echo -e 'Creating kafka topics'
      kafka-topics --bootstrap-server kafka-1:29092 --create --if-not-exists --topic my-topic-1 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1

      echo -e 'Successfully created the following topics:'
      kafka-topics --bootstrap-server kafka-1:29092 --list
      "
```

The healthcheck runs the `kafka-topics.sh` command to check if Kafka is reachable.
i use confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.1.1 image which has `kafka-topics` script for creating a new topic named "my-topic-1"

Comment: `bitnami/kafka` also has `kafka-topics.sh` script