Error while creating Kafka topic from docker_compose
I am trying to create kafka topic from docker compose.
Running on Windows 11.
Here is content of docker-compose.yml file (based on sample files from other posts )
version: '3.9'
networks:
  myNetwork:
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
    networks:
      - myNetwork
  kafka_1:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    user: root
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
    volumes:
      - ./Kafka:/bitnami/kafka
    networks:
      - myNetwork
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
  init-kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    depends_on:
      - kafka_1
    working_dir: /opt/bitnami/kafka/bin
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    networks:
      - myNetwork
    command:
        kafka-topics.sh --create --if-not-exists --topic foo --replication-factor=1 --partitions=3 --bootstrap-server kafka_1:9092

After I running with command
docker compose up -d

I am getting error :
2024-05-12 12:16:15 [2024-05-12 09:16:15,248] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node 1 (/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
2024-05-12 12:16:15 [2024-05-12 09:16:15,391] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: createTopics
2024-05-12 12:16:15  (org.apache.kafka.tools.TopicCommand)
2024-05-12 12:16:15 Error while executing topic command : Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: createTopics

And of course topic was not created.
Is there missing something in docker_compose.yml ? Thanks in advance
UPD : After replacing bitnami image by confluentinc/kafka image ( and corresponding zookeper ) + some changes in encv params , updated docker_compose.yml looks as below ( based also on other related posts)
version: '3.9'
networks:
  myNetwork:
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.4.4
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN: yes
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    networks:
      - myNetwork
  kafka_2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.4.4
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
      - 9093:9093
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://kafka_2:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9093'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: 'PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: 'PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    networks:
      - myNetwork
  init-kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.4.4
    depends_on:
      - kafka_2
    networks:
      - myNetwork
    entrypoint: [ '/bin/sh', '-c' ]
    command: |
      "
      # blocks until kafka is reachable
      kafka-topics --bootstrap-server kafka_2:9092 --list

      echo -e 'Creating kafka topics'
      kafka-topics --bootstrap-server kafka_2:9092 --create --if-not-exists --topic MyTestTopic --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1

      echo -e 'Successfully created the following topics:'
      kafka-topics --bootstrap-server kafka_2:9092 --list
      "

Now it seems working .

The latest bitnami image no longer needs Zookeeper, by the way. I suggest grabbing from the official repo. The error says your init container is trying to find/connect to itself because the advertised listeners are set to 127.0.0.1, rather than kafka_1. Also depends_on doesn't wait for the service to actually start. You can use a healthcheck https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69395147/how-do-i-create-a-kafka-topic-using-a-docker-compose-file/76281698#76281698

Thanks for reply . I replaced bitnami image by confluentinc/cp-kafka  image . It works now .

Feel free to post your solution below. Changing the image alone wouldn't fix the error shown

Of course there is not only image replacement . I added update of the question. Anyway thanks
